# how can I block cert while using self signed CA

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx server with self signed ca.
We are working with mutual authentication, we are as the CA signing the clients CSRs.
Lets say we stopped working with one of the uses,
Is there a way to block it?
I read about CRL but couldnt understand how to use it with self signed CA

How to block one specific user certificate